# How I get intervals on which $f(x)=\sin x -\cos x$ increasing or decreasing?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Here, $f'(x) = \cos x + \sin x$

then $f''(x) = −\sin x + \cos x$,

$f''(x)=0$

where $\sin x=\cos x$ or $\tan x=1$
This happens at $x=\pi/4+\pi k$ for integer $k$

Next what should I do?

Comment: You just have to find $x$ where $f'(x)$ is positive or negative.

Comment: Wouldn't the endpoints of the intervals on which $f$ is increasing or decreasing be where the *first* derivative is zero, i.e., critical points?  You seem to have found potential inflections points, points where the sign of the second derivative *might* change.

Comment: Given that $f$ and its derivatives are continuous, the solutions of $f'(x)=0$ define intervals in which $f'(x)$ will have a defined sign (either positive or negative, which states that $f$ will be increasing or decreasing). For each of those intervals, pick a point $x_0$ in the interval and evaluate $f'(x_0)$.

Comment: Arent you basically done?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
Before you even take the derivatives, use simple trigonometric identities:
$$\cos x = \sin(\pi/2-x) = -\sin(x-\pi/2)\\\sin a+\sin b = 2\sin\frac{a+b}2\cos\frac{a-b}2$$

Answer (score 1):

$f'(x) = \cos x + \sin x$. That means $f(x)$ is increasing on intervals where $f'(x)=\cos x + \sin x > 0$.  .... well just look at the unit circle.   In quadrant I $\sin, \cos$ are both non negative and not both $0$ so $f(x)$ is increasing there.  In the second quadrant $\sin \ge 0$ but $\cos \le 0$ but $\sin x > |\cos x|$ for the first $45$ degrees.  So at $x = 2k \pi + \frac {3\pi}4$, $f(x)$ stops increasing.  For the rest of the second quadrant $|\cos x| > \sin x$ so $f(x)$ is decreasing.  In third quadrant they are both non positive but not both zero so $f(x)$ is decreasing.  And the IV quadrant is just like the  second.

So on the interval $(2k\pi - \frac \pi 4, 2k\pi + \frac {3\pi}4)$, $f(x)$ is increasing and on the interval $(2k\pi + \frac {3\pi}4, 2k\pi + \frac {7\pi}4)$, $f'(x)$ is decreasing.  $f(x)$ has maximum value and $x=2k\pi + \frac {3\pi}4$ where $f(x) = \sin x - \cos x = \frac {\sqrt 2}2 -(-\frac {sqrt 2}2) = \sqrt 2$ and a minimum value ant $x= 2k\pi + \frac {7\pi}4$ where $f(x) = -\sqrt 2$.

Answer (score 1):

First, you would have to find out where your function reaches a maximum or a minimum by computing the derivative of $f(x)$ you will get $f'(x)=0\implies \sin(x)+\cos(x)=0$. What you can do at this point is to use the fact that $\sin^{2}(x)+\cos^{2}(x)=1$ to notice that
$$
\cos(x)=\pm\sqrt{1-\sin^{2}(x)}
$$
Add $\sin(x)$ to both sides you will get :
$$
\sin(x)+\cos(x)=\pm\sqrt{1-\sin^{2}(x)}+\sin(x)
$$
So overall, we need to find $x$ for which :
$$
f'(x)=0 \implies \pm\sqrt{1-\sin^{2}(x)}+\sin(x) = 0 
$$
Here is a hint, if you let $u=\sin(x)$, you will obtain :
$$
\pm\sqrt{1-u^{2}}+u=0  
$$
Square both sides and you will get a quadratic equation from which you can find $u$ then from $u$ you will find the value of $x$ then from the value of $x$ you can study when $f(x)$ increases or decreases.

Answer (score 1):

In order to find where the function is increasing or decreasing, vanishing of the second derivative is irrelevant.

You need to find where the *first* derivative vanishes. In this case, it does where $f'(x)=\cos x+\sin x=0$. This means $\tan x=-1$: there is no problem in dividing by $\cos x$, because when $\cos x=0$ it holds $\sin x\ne0$.

This yields the points $3\pi/4+k\pi$, where $k$ is integer, but we're better to divide the solution set into two, for even and odd $k$, because the tangent has period $\pi$, but sine and cosine have period $2\pi$.

Let's consider the points of the form $3\pi/4+2k\pi$: then
$$
f''(3\pi/4+2k\pi)=-\sin(3\pi/4)+\cos(3\pi/4)=-\sqrt{2}
$$
so these are points of maximum.

For points of the form $3\pi/4+(2k+1)\pi=7\pi/4+2k\pi$ we have
$$
f''(7\pi/4+2k\pi)=-\sin(7\pi/4)+\cos(7\pi/4)=\sqrt{2}
$$
so these are points of minimum.

Now the intervals where the function is increasing or decreasing are easy to determine.